# Selecting nodes with EventTime Between dates x and y

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the below xml file that contain clock in/out punch data for a rolling 17 day period.  The XSLT splits the file at every 250th node.  I would like to take if a bit further and only include punches that have a punch "EventTime between today-3 days and today-10 days.  If the punch EventTime is not between these dates then it is to be ignored and not included in the newly created file.

I am a novice to xslt transformations and after 2 days of Google searches I still am not sure where to start.

Any direction would be appreciated.

Here is a sample of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:TimeAndAttendance xmlns:tns="OptiLink.TimeAndAttendanceFileImporter" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <tns:Punch Direction="Out" EmployeeId="100607240" EventTime="2014-01-11 19:25:00" IsProductive="0" Unit="3004922051"/>
    <tns:Punch Direction="Out" EmployeeId="100627860" EventTime="2014-01-12 19:25:00" IsProductive="0" Unit="3005031600"/>
    <tns:Punch Direction="Out" EmployeeId="100678310" EventTime="2014-01-13 19:25:00" IsProductive="0" Unit="3005536000"/>
    <tns:Punch Direction="Out" EmployeeId="100679310" EventTime="2014-01-14 19:25:00" IsProductive="0" Unit="3006225500"/>
    <tns:Punch Direction="Out" EmployeeId="100675370" EventTime="2014-01-15 19:26:00" IsProductive="0" Unit="3000210801"/>
    <tns:Punch Direction="Out" EmployeeId="100615780" EventTime="2014-01-16 19:26:00" IsProductive="0" Unit="3000228501"/>
    <tns:Punch Direction="In" EmployeeId="100712780" EventTime="2014-01-17 19:26:00" IsProductive="0" Unit="3000231600"/>
    <tns:Punch Direction="Out" EmployeeId="100613280" EventTime="2014-01-18 19:26:00" IsProductive="0" Unit="3000314500"/>
    <tns:Punch Direction="Out" EmployeeId="100629300" EventTime="2014-01-19 19:26:00" IsProductive="0" Unit="3000314550"/>
    <tns:Punch Direction="In" EmployeeId="100725580" EventTime="2014-01-20 19:26:00" IsProductive="0" Unit="3000327400"/>
    <tns:Punch Direction="In" EmployeeId="100696010" EventTime="2014-01-21 19:26:00" IsProductive="0" Unit="3001931600"/>
    <tns:Punch Direction="Out" EmployeeId="100613280" EventTime="2014-01-22 19:26:00" IsProductive="0" Unit="3000314500"/>
    <tns:Punch Direction="Out" EmployeeId="100629300" EventTime="2014-01-23 19:26:00" IsProductive="0" Unit="3000314550"/>
    <tns:Punch Direction="In" EmployeeId="100725580" EventTime="2014-01-24 19:26:00" IsProductive="0" Unit="3000327400"/>
    <tns:Punch Direction="In" EmployeeId="100696010" EventTime="2014-01-25 19:26:00" IsProductive="0" Unit="3001931600"/>
    <tns:Punch Direction="In" EmployeeId="100725580" EventTime="2014-01-26 19:26:00" IsProductive="0" Unit="3000327400"/>
    <tns:Punch Direction="In" EmployeeId="100696010" EventTime="2014-01-27 19:26:00" IsProductive="0" Unit="3001931600"/>
</tns:TimeAndAttendance>
```

And here is my XSLT that splits the file into many files:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tns="OptiLink.TimeAndAttendanceFileImporter" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:param name="pPunches" select="250"/>
    <!-- Get the filename -->
    <xsl:variable name="filename" select="tokenize(base-uri(.), '/')[last()]"/>
    <!-- Split the filename using '\.' -->
    <xsl:variable name="filenamepart" select="tokenize($filename, '\.')"/>
    <!-- Remove the file extension -->
    <xsl:variable name="filenamepartfinal" select="$filenamepart[1]"/>
    <!-- Run the split -->
    <xsl:template match="tns:TimeAndAttendance">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="tns:Punch"
                                group-adjacent="(position()-1) idiv $pPunches">
            <xsl:result-document  href="TimeAndAttendance\{$filenamepartfinal}-{current-grouping-key()}.xml">
                <tns:TimeAndAttendance>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </tns:TimeAndAttendance>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EventTime` values are almost in the correct lexical form for conversion to `xs:dateTime` (they'd just need the two parts to be separated by `T` instead of by a space), so you could try something like

```
<xsl:template match="tns:TimeAndAttendance">
    <!-- xs:dateTime representing ten days ago -->
    <xsl:variable name="from" select="current-dateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration('P10D')" as="xs:dateTime"/>
    <!-- xs:dateTime representing three days ago -->
    <xsl:variable name="to" select="current-dateTime() - xs:dayTimeDuration('P3D')" as="xs:dateTime"/>
    <!-- filter just the punches between $from and $to dates -->
    <xsl:for-each-group select="tns:Punch[
          xs:dateTime(translate(@EventTime, ' ', 'T')) gt $from and
          xs:dateTime(translate(@EventTime, ' ', 'T')) lt $to]"
        group-adjacent="(position()-1) idiv $pPunches">
```

Comment: That is the answer!  Thanks Ian.